# Running a Batch File that Checks for a Process if not running Run a batch file Windows 10

Tags: batch-file

Windows 10 I can't seem to get the batch file to activate the second batch file if the process is not running. First part works fine, calling the second batch file is broken. I tried to call, I tried `%~dp0`, like this: `%~dp0MyProgram.bat`

```
@echo off
:start
cls
set proc=zm.exe
set runme=c:\ZM\zcash.bat
set time=30

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %proc%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%proc%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
echo Everything is OK 
timeout /t %time%
goto :start ) || (
echo ERROR! restarting service
taskkill /IM "%proc%" /F
else (start "" "%runme%")
)
timeout /t %time%
goto :start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite saying you'd tried it, you should use `Call` because you're wanting to return to the same script upon it's completion.

Perhaps something like this would work for you?

```bat
@Echo off
Set "proc=zm.exe"
Set "runme=C:\ZM\zcash.bat"
Set "secs=30"

:Loop
ClS
TaskList | FindStr /I "\<%proc%\>" >Nul && (Echo Everything is OK) || (
    Echo ERROR! starting service
    Call "%runme%")
Timeout %secs% /NoBreak >Nul
GoTo Loop
```

*Note: I changed the variable name to `%secs%` because `%TIME%` is already a defined system variable.*

Comment: That is beautiful, put me in the right direction. Thank you very much for the reply.